# Trouble with Map iterate

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, dictionary

I want to iterate Map, where the value is another Map.
I have this method:

```
 public void test(){
   Map<Integer, Double> map1 = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();
   Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Double>> map2 = new HashMap<Integer, Map<Integer, Double>>();
   map1.put(1,1.1);
   map1.put(2,2.2);
   map1.put(3,3.3);
   map2.put(1,map1);
   map1.clear();
   map1.put(4,4.4);
   map1.put(5,5.5);
   map1.put(6,6.6);
   map2.put(2,map1);

   for (Map.Entry<Integer, Map<Integer, Double>> entry : map2.entrySet()){
       Log.d("test", "map2 key " + entry.getKey());
       Map<Integer, Double> tempMap = new HashMap<Integer, Double>(entry.getValue());
       for (Map.Entry<Integer, Double> entry1 : tempMap.entrySet()){
           Log.d("map", "map1 key " + entry1.getKey() + "map1 value " + entry1.getValue());
       }
   }
```

And I see in logs this:

```
map2 key 1
map1 key 4 map1 value 4.4
map1 key 5 map1 value 5.5
map1 key 6 map1 value 6.6
map2 key 2
map1 key 4 map1 value 4.4
map1 key 5 map1 value 5.5
map1 key 6 map1 value 6.6
```

What's the problem?

Comment: tma;dr (too many answers, didn't read): `map2` shares the same reference to `map1` in both put() so it displays the same results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that you want the keys 1, 2, and 3 to be available in `map1`.

The problem is that you have reused the same map, `map1`, and inserted it into `map2` twice.  So the cumulative results of all operations on `map1` is that only 4, 5, and 6 are in the map.  Visually:

```
   /1 ====v
map2    map1 -> (4 => 4.4), (5 => 5.5), (6 => 6.6)
   \2 ====^
```

To get two different maps, don't clear `map1` after inserting it the first time, create a new map.  Replace

```
map1.clear();
```

with

```
map1 = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();
```

That will yield this:

```
   /1====> (1 => 1.1), (2 => 2.2), (3 => 3.3)
map2    
   \2====> (4 => 4.4), (5 => 5.5), (6 => 6.6)
            ^
map1  ------/
```

Answer (score 2):

> What's the problem?

You've put the same value in the "outer" map for both entries: a reference to the single `Map<Integer, Double>` you've created. When you call `put`, it *just* adds the reference to the map - it doesn't take a deep copy of the object at that point and store a reference to the copy.

If you want two separate maps, you need to create them explicitly:

```
Map<Integer, Double> inner1 = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();
inner1.put(1,1.1);
inner1.put(2,2.2);
inner1.put(3,3.3);
Map<Integer, Double> inner2 = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();
inner2.put(4,4.4);
inner2.put(5,5.5);
inner2.put(6,6.6);

Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Double>> outer = new HashMap<Integer, Map<Integer, Double>>();
outer.put(1, inner1);
outer.put(2, inner2);
```

(You don't *have* to use two different variables here, but I find it helpful.)

It's very important that you understand the difference between references and objects in Java - the value of a variable is *never, ever* an object... it's always either a primitive or a reference. So if you write something like:

```
StringBuilder builder1 = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder builder2 = builder1;
builder2.append("foo");
System.out.println(builder1);
```

... it will print out "foo" because you've only got a single `StringBuilder`, with two variables that happen to both have references to the same object.

Answer (score 1):

You are not creating two `Map` instances, only one and you reuse it (with the  `map.clear`).

Do:

```
map2.put(1,map1);
map1 = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();
map1.put(4,4.4);
map1.put(5,5.5);
map1.put(6,6.6);
map2.put(2,map1);
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `map1.clear();` you are just clearing the same map that is being referenced by `map1`, and then filling it up. That will replace the old key-value mappings. Note the actual map object is still the same.

Then when you fill up new value, the two references you add to `map2`, will both being holding reference to the same map object, will show you the same output.

Instead of clearing the map, you should create a new map.